# How to copy a repository completely separate from the original, not a fork?

Tags: git, github

I have a shared repository that our company uses for test development.  As it grew hugely cumbersome, we decided to refactor each team's tests into separate repos, and also separate the common testing  chunks (TestNG, Selenium, BrowserMob, etc.) into a common repo.

Originally, I just forked into a repo for my team:  originalRepo/testStuff ==> myteam/testStuff.  I then pruned out all of the test code from other teams, as I no longer needed to maintain it.  Creating a branch for new work, I then created a pull request to merge that branch into it's master of my fork:
myteam/testStuff-new ==> myteam/testStuff.

However, everyone else receive notice of that pull request, thinking I was about to delete the 1500 or so files from the originalRepo/testStuff.  After administering CPR throughout the test teams, we determined that I hadn't broken anything.  However, the current setup is to close to the original, and I would like to completely sever all ties in Git.

The options I see:
1. manually copy/paste it all to a new repo (i.e., myteam/severedRepo).  This seems fraught with error.
2. keep my existing fork and somehow sever it from originalRepo/testStuff.  This seems to require admin help.

Is there another way?  Clean, reliable, recommended?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the correct permissions to create new repositories, this should be pretty easy. All you have to do is create a new bare repository and push the contents of your existing repo to it.

1. Create a new repo at `myteam/severedRepo`.
2. In your local repository, remove the reference to the original repository `git remote rm origin`.
3. Add a new remote pointing to you newly created repo `git remote add origin https://github.com/myteam/severedRepo.git`. When you create a new blank repository, Github will show you the url that you should use when adding the new origin.
4. Push your local repository to the new remote `git push -u origin master`.

Most of the information above will be displayed on the page Github shows after you create a new repository. The important thing to take away though is that the only actual connection between one git repository and another is via remotes. If you remove the remotes, there is no longer any link between them. Technically, Github could be smart enough to determine a shared history between two repositories by inspecting their commit history, but I don't think they actually do this.